# This app wont run unless you update googleplayservices in android emulator

Tags: android, google-maps

**What i am doing** ::I am trying to use Maps in emulator

**My emulator setup**::

[image]

**Error message**::

[image]

---

**What i have done** ::

- I have updated the google play services in sdk- still same error
- I tried Gennymotion- no play services at present
- I saw some people saying API-19 can run map but, still i am not able
  to run
- i don't have a device
- Should i need to do something to update, if so what is it ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed these

```
Install com.android.vending.apk (Google Play Store, v.3.10.9)
Install com.google.android.gms.apk (Google Play Service, v.2.0.12)
```

apks in emulator.

Follow [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094787/map-not-getting-in-emulator-android-api-v2/19317114#19317114) steps which I answered for another question..

Comment: I followed steps .... i got message ... install failes already exixts .... any inputs ?

Comment: try to use -r like  `adb install -r apkname.apk` means you uninstall before install -r is used for remove purpose. For more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449540/failure-install-failed-already-exists-when-i-tried-to-update-my-application

Comment: I tried similarly .... I am getting message as:: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES] ..... Should i need to take any other parameters ?