# React Native doesn't work in physical Android Device

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, build

I'm having issues to run my react native apps in physical devices. When I execute react-native run-android using a Genymotion virtual device for example, it works perfectly.

But when I try to execute in physical connected devices, i get multiple errors.
I tried 2 different devices, and checked with "adb devices" if they are connected, they do.

When I try to just execute "react-native run-android", I get the following error: (and nothing appears on physical device)

[image: react-native run-android]

But when I check for devices, and use the device id when executing like:
"react-native run-android --deviceId E6D68T7P99999999", I get the new error: (but now appearing "Unable to load script from assets 'Index.android.bundle'." on the device)

[image: react-native run-android --deviceId E6D68T7P99999999]

Also I have tried some other ways
In my project folder android/app/build.gradle, I changed where it was 
compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
to
compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.44.0"
This makes to BUILD appears SUCESSFULL, but otherwise, in the physical device appears like:
"The development server returned response error code: 404
URL: etc etc.
BODY: Cannot GET /index.android.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false"

[image: Changing build.gradle from "+" to "0.44.0"]

Can anyone help me please? I tried all the ways, using react-native start, killing process on port 8081 but NOTHING works with me!

React Native version: 0.44.0,
Windows 7 x64,
Tried on 2 different devices and 
Developer mode and usb debugging mode ON

Answer (score 0):

Try using adb install -r to reinstall your apk.  I notice that your error says the apk already exists.

[Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS] when I tried to update my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449540/failure-install-failed-already-exists-when-i-tried-to-update-my-application)

Comment: Hello Lewis, I ran the command line you suggested but apparently nothing changes, still giving me error messages

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today and I do not know whether you have solved your problem, but for me, I had to add "ANDROID_HOME" environment variable(specify the SDK path). I hope it helps anyone who might come in contact with such problem

Answer (score -1):

There's actually a hand full of things you could try to fix this problem.

1) `npm install`

2) `npm start -- --reset-cache`

3) Delete `node_modules` then `npm install`

4)`cd` to `android` and `gradlew clean`

5) Make sure all of your Java SDKs or what not are in the correct system path.

6) Restart your computer then try again.

Let me know your progress once you tried these options!

Comment: Andrew, thanks for your answer.
Except the 3 and 4 steps, I have tried it all, gonna do it today and I post it here later

Comment: @paulinhok14 I wish you the best of luck!

Comment: Hello Andrew, sorry for the delay on the answer, I got several problems with the RN update and lack of time... I did all the things you suggested, still can't run it on physical device :( any other suggestions?

Comment: Yes, if I just execute react-native run-android, it gives me error: Failed to load it all

Comment: and if I execute react-native run-android --deviceId ~id~ , the app loads in the phone but displays: Cannot find entry file index.android.js

Comment: I have never seen that first ever before. But as for the second error, to fix it, you need to be running metro bundler. `npm start -- --reset-cache` fixes that.